# Magento - Google Checkout Free Shipping Problem

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I have set up Google Checkout on my Magento store and I'm using Flat Rates for the shipping.  the problem is if I put zero for the rate ie. free shipping I get a message when I go to checkout saying that I don't ship to that country.

If I add any value into the rate (even 0.01) it works fine.

Here is a screen of the config which doesn't work:
http://skitch.com/a1anm/dqmw2/configuration-system-magento-admin

Here is a screen of the config which does work:
http://skitch.com/a1anm/dqmw9/configuration-system-magento-admin

Here is a screen of the error I get at checkout if I set the shipping rate to 0.00:
http://skitch.com/a1anm/dqmim/secure-checkout-with-google

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

I believe (and I can't check, so I'm going off of memory here) that if the rate is set to 0.00, the Shipping module returns false and there are no available shipment methods. I think you'll have to create a cart discount rule in order to get it to return true and get you over to GC with free shipping.

Comment: I'm not sure what rule I can create so that only customers in the UK get the free shipping.  If I do it by shipping region then it won't get applied before getting sent to google.

Is there any other way I can get the module to return 'true'?

Comment: Give this a shot before modifying the model. Go to Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules from admin. Fill out the rule information, the make the conditions. You can specify UK only, and I would say anything over 0.01 qualifies for free shipping. Then send a test order through and you should be ok.

Comment: No joy I'm afraid.  I used these rules and said anything which matches the rules gets free shipping:

http://skitch.com/a1anm/dqxrh/free-shipping-google-checkout-magento-admin

The free shipping doesn't get passed to Google Checkout.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Check this: System > Configuration > Shipping Methods - is Free Shipping enabled? If not, enable it with an order minimum of 99999.

Comment: It is currently enabled as I use this for the free shipping when users checkout using the one step checkout:
http://skitch.com/a1anm/dqt1i/configuration-system-magento-admin

Comment: Ahh ok, well, in that case I'm not entirely sure. I wouldn't edit the model, because that might create some issues. But, there's no reason why it shouldn't work with what you setup.